# Springboot + Thymeleaf + HTML replace meta tag content attribute with dynamic value

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf, redirect, meta-tags

I have a requirement to populate the meta tag's content attribute in my html with a dynamic value. I am using Spring boot with thymeleaf templating engine. I tried looking up for a solution but all the solutions out there are either in bits or pieces or don't answer my questions directly. I dont want to use JQuery or any other javascript framework due to the nature of my project, hence posting this query.

Already tried various thymeleaf out of box functionalities

```java
    @Value("${redirect.url}")
    String redirectUrl;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    @CrossOrigin
    public String index( Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("url", redirectUrl);
        return "index";
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url="/> <!-- Need to be able to populate dynamic value  by using thymeleaf-->
</head>
</html>
```

I except url tag to contain the actual URL passed from my controller

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thymeleaf supports the `th:content` attribute natively.  No need to go with a javascript hack. [See the list of supported attributes](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes).

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" th:content="|0; url=${url}|" />
```

Comment: And you can always fall back to `th:attr` if needed.

Comment: Thanks for an optimized and precise solution to the problem

Answer (score 1):

I want to post a working solution to benefit myself and others who stumble upon this page in future

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url="/>

    <script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        var myUrl = /*[[${url}]]*/ 'http:localhost:3000';
        var myFinalUrl = "0; url=" + myUrl;
        document.querySelector('meta[http-equiv="Refresh"]').setAttribute('content',myFinalUrl);
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```